# search string for specific word and replace it

Tags: php, regex, search

I think it is a regex I need.

I have a text-input where users may search my website.
They may use the word "`ELLER`" between search phrases, which is in english equal to "`OR`".

My search engine however, requires it in english, so I need to replace all **ELLER** in the query string with **OR** instead.

How can I do this?

Btw, it is php...

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
str_replace("ELLER", "OR", $string);
```

http://php.net/manual/de/function.str-replace.php

Comment: I agree, use str_replace. It is much faster than using a regex.

Comment: as this but use the strings `" ELLER "` and `" OR "` (note spaces)

Comment: Heed Segfault's advice, otherwise a search for "Helen Keller" or "Uri Geller" won't work as expected

Comment: @Segfault Spaces aren't the only way to delineate a word (other possibilities are punctuation or the beginning or end of the string). You can't really effectively match only full words without regex.

Answer (score 7):

If you have a specific word you want to replace, there's no need for regex, you can use [`str_replace`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) instead:

```
$string = str_replace("ELLER", "OR", $string);
```

When what you're looking for is not dynamic, using PHP's string functions will be faster than using regular expressions.

If you want to ensure that `ELLER` is only replaced when it is a full-word match, and not contained within another word, you can use [`preg_replace`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) and the [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) anchor (`\b`):

```
$string = preg_replace('/\bELLER\b/', 'OR', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Should note too that you can also pass str_replace an array of values to change and an array of values to change to such as:

`str_replace(array('item 1', 'item 2'), 'items', $string);`

or

`str_replace(array('item 1', 'item 2'), array('1 item', '2 item'), $string);`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// data
$name = "Daniel";
$order = 132456;

// String to be searched
$string = "Hi [name], thank you for the order [order_id]. The order is for [name]";

// replace rules - replace [name] with $name(Danile) AND [order_id] with $order(123456)
$text_to_send = str_replace(array('[name]', '[order_id]'), array($name, $order), $string);

// print the result
echo $text_to_send;
```

"Hi Damiel, thank you for the order 123456. The order is for Daniel"